# Hide Tabbar Controller Tabbar iOS issue

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, hide, uitabbar

I have a tabbar controller with 3 tabs, each tab has navigation controller, on root view controller of each navigation controller i want tabbar and on other view controller in same navigation controller i dont want tabbar.

Any solution?

Comment: set the alpha of the tabbar to 0 and userinteraction to false

Comment: @MohammadBashirSidani i dont want to show tabbar at all

Comment: Setting alpha value 0 to tab Bar hides all items and including tab bar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set self.tabBarController?.tabBar.isHidden = true in viewWillAppear method of your controller when you don't want tabbar

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        self.tabBarController?.tabBar.isHidden = true
}
```

Comment: tabbar gets hidden and place where tabbar is placed gets black

Comment: set your tabBar style = Default and checked Translucent of your Tabbar Conroller in storyboard

Answer (score 0):

Setting alpha value 0 to tab Bar hides all items and including tab bar
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should set the tabbar `alpha` to 0. This will hide the UITabBar.
However you need to set `isUserInteractionEnabled` to false since even when its hided, the buttons are there & clickable still!

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

1. Set Transculent property of Tab bar to true or check the same from storyboard
2. Set hidesTabbarWhen Pushed property of Tab bar to true or check the same from storyboard
3. Set Tab bar hidden true on view controller where you want Tab bar and set Tab bar hidden to false on view controller where you don't want Tab bar